# Ruby pattern match all but last

Tags: ruby, replace

I would like to create a Ruby pattern to replace all but the last occurrence of a letter.

For example, replace all:

```
"}"
```

with the string:

```
"} something "
```

Turn this string:

```
"{ anything }   { anything } { anything }"
```

to:

```
"{ anything } something    { anything } something  { anything }"
```

EDIT:

What I've used so far:

```
replaceString = "} something"
string.gsub("}", replaceString).reverse.sub(replaceString.reverse, "}").reverse
```

but I don't think it is very effective.

Comment: We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question- if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead:

```
str = "{ anything }   { anything } { anything }"
pattern = /\}(?=.*\})/
str.gsub(pattern, "} Something")

=> "{ anything } Something   { anything } Something { anything }"
```

Comment: This works for only one line, if there are any '\n' in the string it doesnt work

Comment: For multiline use `pattern = /\}(?=.*\})/m`

Answer (score 2):

In my other answer I didn't tell you that regex is an overkill for such a simple problem, not to mention that it is probably the slowest possible solution.

I would prefer a simple tailored solution like this one:

```
def replace_all_but_last str, substr1, substr2
  str.dup.tap { |result|
    index = str.rindex substr1
    result[0...index] = result[0...index].gsub(substr1, substr2)
  }
end

str = "{ anything }   { anything } { anything }"
replace_all_but_last str, "}", "} something"
```